# Mac Apache / PHP will not start session for only one site and segmentation fault

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, segmentation-fault

Mac Apache 2.4 / PHP Version 7.3.6 stack.  I'm not using MAMP.  I have several web-project folders in the web-root directory.  All sites work fine except two which are both WordPress sites with similar theme/code.

When accessing index.php file of those two projects the browser wont finish loading the page and gives an error page `"The Connection has been reset"`.  I can login and reset the permalinks and then the page will load again.

I have concluded that it is the .htacess file since if I delete it (or reset permalinks as mentioned above), the page will load fine.

However, after some time (hours or even the next day), the problem has returns.  I have scanned for viruses using WordFence but I have not gone through all the source code to try and find the problem.

The /var/log/apache2/error_log file output includes this for every page load I attempt:

```
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:31.470224 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37499 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:32.544341 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37677 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:33.620666 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37680 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:33.620762 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37679 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:34.707740 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37684 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:34.707818 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37683 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:34.707840 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37682 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:34.707859 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37681 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Mon Jul 22 17:50:35.780855 2019] [core:notice] [pid 80] AH00052: child pid 37685 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I have tried clearing the browser cache. Safari, Firefox, and Chome all behave the same.

I have also md5 checksummed the fresh and functional .htaccess file and the .htaccess file when the page refuses to load.  They md5 outputs are the same.

What could be causing the .htaccess file to cause Apache to Seg-fault?  Is there another possible explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have AddType directives in .htaccess and remove them.
I had the same problem which started with Catalina, and removing AddType fixed the problem.
My PHP version is 7.3.25 and Apache version is 2.4.41.